# iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed and iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed

Tags: networking, drivers, intel-wireless

I had installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my ASUS GL502VMK 
During the boot, i get

```
KLINGON:~$ dmesg | grep wifi
[    4.408487] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.412642] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.413216] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.418940] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 31.532993.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.435149] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    4.511080] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: f4:96:34:33:8b:64
```

I'll try to download the driver, but I don't able to discovery it.

How can fix it or download the drivers ?

Thanks all
Chris

Comment: You can try to install `linux-firmware` package.

Comment: But it seems that -32 and -33 are not available in [artful](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=iwlwifi-8000C). Does your wi-fi working normally? These messages about firmware maybe simple warning. Does your system hang after these messages as in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1728651)?

Comment: It is simply informational. The driver looked for -33 and -32 and didn’t find them. It found and loaded -31 and initialized. May we assume that your wireless works as expected? If not, what is going wrong.

Comment: The system works properly on Wi-Fi, although it seems to slow down sometimes

Answer (score 0):

There are no iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode and iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode yet while it tries to load them.  The latest in /lib/firmware/ are iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode and iwlwifi-8265-31.ucode

```
B250C:~$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0--33.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0--33.ucode
srcversion:     339D7D3BD0DD2A9C7FE616F
```